# hiding blank columns in crystal reports while exporting to excel

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report having 5 columns and when I am exporting it to excel I am getting some blank columns .
So I want to remove the column when there is no data while exporting.
Could any one please help how to do this

Comment: Have you tried changing the export format to use one of the "Data Only" formats when exporting to Excel?  Its hard to give much of an answer to this question without knowing more about the report's design.  There are many things that can cause this kind of problem when exporting to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, you can avoid blank columns by ensuring there is no horizontal space between report objects. You can add vertical guidelines and snap objects to these guidelines to facilitate avoiding spaces.

But for some scenarios, such as reports that also include CrossTabs or parameter-driven optional columns, the problem can't be avoided even with 'Excel (Data Only)' export format.

A few 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools can delete blank columns and blank rows as part of the Excel export process. Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).